# Python [Errno 13] Permission denied when opening some images

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to handle some files that are created in a folder, but sometimes, when opening the file, python returns me [Errno 13]: Permission denied.

I'm simply doing

```
file = open(file_path, 'rb')
```

and the weirdest of all is that most of the times the files get opened correctly and the error is not related to some specific file (tested it several times).
I've already tried to change file_path formatting but had no effect.

I'm using python 3.5 and watchdog lib to watch the directory for file creation events, then I get the src_path of the event and open it. Also, running on Windows 10.

Comment: When trying to open a same file, sometimes an error is raised, but sometimes it works? Such an inconstency could be caused by trying to open a file that is already open elsewhere...

Comment: ``sometimes`` ... ``most of the times`` ... how are we supposed to replicate the error and help you, if even you can not successfully reproduce the error? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Rightleg but when I run the code again and try to open the file that caused the error it works. And the file is opened only once in the code, since it is triggered by its creation.

Comment: @mpf82 the error occurs eventually when I'm opening files, I haven't found a pattern for it, and I've already tried to look for file names, file permissions, user permissions and file size, but this have not made difference in the error occurrence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, looks like the problem was a bit up in the code. As I've mentioned, I was using watchdog lib to detect file creation, and in that event I opened the file that was created. The thing is that the file creation event does not occur when the file is done beeing moved/pasted/created, but as the first few bytes come to the directory. So the problem was that I was attempting to open the file before the "creation" proccess was finished, and so it was still being written.

I searched for a way to get the finished-writing event, but watchdog lib does not have this feature, and it looks like that finished-writing events are linux only feature.

So now I wait some time before opening the file through a timer thread, and it seems to work pretty fine, since I don't need instant action on new files nor need to handle huge files.

Comment: Did you stopped to use `watchdog`?

Answer (score 3):

I was also getting the same error "Permission denied", but if you wait for like 2 seconds after the create event and then read the file, it gets resolved.

Answer (score 2):

You may add the below snipped to wait till the operation to complete.

```
init_size = -1
while True:
    current_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
    if current_size == init_size:
        break
    else:
        init_size = os.path.getsize(event.src_path)
        time.sleep(2)
print("file copy has now finished")
```